# Question about periodicity in Fibonacci numbers

Tags: calculus, group-theory, prime-numbers, irrational-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

This is related to Pisano periods, that is, the periods of the Fibonacci numbers modulo $k=2, 3, \cdots$. I am studying the sequence $x(n+1)=\{b x(n)\}$ (here the brackets represent the fractional part function) with $b=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ and $x(1) = 1/k, k=2, 3, \cdots$. These sequences are also periodic.

I tried several values of $k$ and in all the cases both periods (Pisano periods and periods from my sequences) were identical. Is this a coincidence, or a well known result easy to prove? For the context, read my article on randomness theory, [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/fascinating-new-results-in-the-theory-of-randomness). This fact is discussed in section 3.3.(b). My sequence is associated with the golden ratio numeration system, a well known numeration system with an irrational base.